# Issues with swipe and/or animate in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, event-listener

What it is:
I am having an issue with my swipeable form.  It uses a vanilla JS method to achieve swipe recognition and .animate to cycle through each part of the form.

My problem:
When too many swipes are performed in succession or too many next buttons are clicked in succession, the .animate seems to fail and they start to pile up in the center of the visible area.

Things I've tried:
I've tried stopPropagation() and setTimeout(), but neither have helped.  I've also tried removing the listeners at the start of their function and adding them back at the end of the nextPrev() function, which also didn't correct the issue.

I'm not sure where exactly it is going wrong and therefore don't know how to troubleshoot this.  I've tried different things at various stages and nothing seems to correct this issue.  I am looking for a way to prevent this from happening.

I apologize for not presenting an MCVE, I left everything in intentionally so someone could experience cycling through the form and reproduce the issue.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
    <style>
      body {
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 2em;
        }
      #form {
        display: flex;
        margin: auto;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        width: 750px;
        height: 750px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
      #btns {
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        width: 250px;
        height: 50px;
        }
      #back {
        float: left;
        }
      #next {
        float: right;
        }
      table {
        margin: auto;
        }
      .part:not(:first-child) {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        left: 5000px;
        }
      .part:first-child {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        }
      input[type=text],input[type=number],input[type=date],input[type=time], select {
        width: 500px;
        padding: 30px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        border: 1px solid Black;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 1em;
        color: Black;
        }
    input[type=radio] {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        }
    input[type=checkbox] {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="form">
    <div id="0" class="part"><h3>Driver Information</h3></div>
    <div id="1" class="part">Company:<br><input type="text" name="carrier"></div>
    <div id="2" class="part">Station:<br><table>
    <tr><td>PDX:</td><td><input type="radio" id="pdx" name="address"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>EUG:</td><td><input type="radio" id="pdx" name="address"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>SEA:</td><td><input type="radio" id="pdx" name="address"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>SFO:</td><td><input type="radio" id="pdx" name="address"></td></tr></table></div>
    <div id="3" class="part">Name:<br><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name"></div>
    <div id="4" class="part">Employee Number:<br><input type="number" name="employeeNumber" placeholder="Your Employee Number"></div>
    <div id="5" class="part">Date:<br><input type="date" id="date" name="date"></div>
    <div id="6" class="part">Time:<br><input type="time" id="time" name="time"></div>
    <div id="7" class="part"><h3>Vehicle<br>Information</h3></div>
    <div id="8" class="part">Tractor/Truck Number:<br><input type="number" id="tractorTruckNumber" name="tractorTruckNumber"></div>
    <div id="9" class="part">Odometer:<br><input type="number" id="odometer" name="odometer"></div>    
    <div id="10" class="part"><h4><p>Vehicle Inspection<br><small></small></p></h4></div>
    <div id="11" class="part">
    <table>
    <tr><td>Air Compressor:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="aircompressor"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Air Lines:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="airlines"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Battery:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="battery"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Belts and Hoses:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="beltsandhoses"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Body:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="body"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div id="12" class="part">
    <table>
    <tr><td>Brake Accessories:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="brakeaccessories"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Brakes, Parking:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="brakesparking"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Brakes, Service:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="brakesservice"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Clutch:</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="clutch"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Coupling Devices:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="couplingdevices"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div id="13" class="part">
    <table>
    <tr><td>Defroster/Heater:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="defrosterheater"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Drive Line:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="driveline"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Engine:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="engine"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Exhaust:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="exhaust"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Fifth Wheel:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="fifthwheel"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div id="14" class="part">
    <table>
    <tr><td>Fluid Levels:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="fluidlevels"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Frame and Assembly:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="frameandassembly"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Front Axle:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="frontaxle"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Fuel Tanks:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="fueltanks"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Horn:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="horn"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div id="15" class="part">
    <table>
    <tr><td>Lights:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="lights"></td></tr>
    </table>
    <small><center><p>Head/Stop, Tail/Dash, Turn Indicators, Clearance/Marker</p></center></small>
    </div>
    <div id="16" class="part">
    <table>
    <tr><td>Mirrors:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="mirrors"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Muffler:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="muffler"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Oil Pressure:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="oilpressure"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Radiator:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="radiator"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Read End:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="rearend"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Reflectors:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="reflectors"></td></tr> 
    </table>
    </div>
    <div id="17" class="part">
    <table>
    <tr><td>Safety Equipment:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="safetyequipment"></td></tr>
    </table>
    <small><center><p>Fire Extinguisher, Flags/Flares/Fusees, Reflective Triangles, Spare Bulbs/Fuses, Spare Seal Beam</p></center></small>
    </div>
    <div id="18" class="part">
    <table>
    <tr><td>Starter:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="starter"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Steering:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="steering"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Suspension System:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="suspensionsystem"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Tire Chains:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="tirechains"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Tires:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="tires"></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>Transmission:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="transmission"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div id="19" class="part">
    <table>
    <tr><td>Trip Recorder:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="triprecorder"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Wheels and Rims</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="wheelsandrims"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Windows</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="windows"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Windshield Wipers:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="windshieldwipers"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Other:</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="truck" id="other"></td></tr> 
    </table>
    </div>
    <div id="20" class="part">Remarks:<br><input type="text" id="truckremarks"></div>
    <div id="21" class="part"><h3>Trailer Inspection</h3></div>
    <div id="22" class="part">Trailer Number:<br><input type="number" id="trailernumber"><br><h6>(if no trailer, click next)</h6></div>

    </div>
    <div id="btns"><input type="button" id="back" onclick="nextPrev(-1)" value="<< Back"><input type="button" id="next" onclick="nextPrev(1);" value="Next >>"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
  var part = $('.part')
  var currentPart = 0;
  checkButtons();
  var isSwiping = false;

  function startSwipe(){
    if (isSwiping){
      return false;
      }
      else {
      isSwiping = true;
      $('#back, #next').attr('disabled',true);
      return true;
      }
    }
  function endSwipe(){
    $('#back, #next').removeAttr('disabled');
    isSwiping = false;
    }

  function nextPrev(n){
    if (startSwipe()){//this doesn't work when swiping with startSwipe(), but buttons still work
      if (n === 1){
        if (currentPart !== part.length-1){
          $('#'+currentPart).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({'left':'-5000px'},500,function(){
            $(this).css({'left':'-5000px'});//set current left
            });//move current left
          $('#'+(currentPart+n)).delay(200).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({'left':'0'},500,function(){
            $(this).css({'left':'0'});//set next centered
            currentPart = currentPart + n;
            checkButtons();
            endSwipe();
            });//move next right   
          }
        }
      if (n === -1){
        if (currentPart !==0){
          $('#'+currentPart).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({'left':'5000px'},500,function(){
            $('#'+currentPart).css({'left':'5000px'});//set current right
            });//move current left
          $('#'+(currentPart+n)).delay(200).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({'left':'0'},500,function(){
            $('#'+(currentPart+n)).css({'left':'0'});//set next centered
            currentPart = currentPart + n;
            checkButtons();
            endSwipe();
            });//move next right
          }
        }
      }  
    }

  function checkButtons(){
    if (currentPart == 0){
      $('#back').css({'display':'none'});
      }
    else if (currentPart == part.length-1){
      $('#next').css({'display':'none'});
      }
    else {
      $('#back').css({'display':'block'});
      $('#next').css({'display':'block'});
      }
    }

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);        
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, false);

var xDown = null;                                                        
var yDown = null;

function getTouches(evt) {
  return evt.touches ||             // browser API
         evt.originalEvent.touches; // jQuery
}                                                     

function handleTouchStart(evt) {
  if (startSwipe()){
    const firstTouch = getTouches(evt)[0];                                      
    xDown = firstTouch.clientX;                                      
    yDown = firstTouch.clientY;  
  }
};                                                

function handleTouchMove(evt) {
  if (isSwiping){
    if ( ! xDown || ! yDown ) {
        return;
    }
    var xUp = evt.touches[0].clientX;                                    
    var yUp = evt.touches[0].clientY;

    var xDiff = xDown - xUp;
    var yDiff = yDown - yUp;

    if ( Math.abs( xDiff ) > Math.abs( yDiff ) ) {/*most significant*/
        if ( xDiff > 0 ) {
            nextPrev(1);
        } else {
            nextPrev(-1);
        }                       
    }

    /* reset values */
    xDown = null;
    yDown = null;
  }
};

function handleTouchEnd(evt) {
  endSwipe();
  };
  </script>
</html>
```

update:  ariel's solution is a good one, though it did not fix my problem.  This sort of flagging is important, and my code should've already been equipped with it.  I am still experiencing issues, though I found something promising here: https://css-tricks.com/full-jquery-animations/
Though it does not fix my problem completely, it is getting very close to a solution and I will update when I have one.

Comment: You need to add the code here, the link doesn't work. Also add your other code so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Oh, dang.  I've added the code.  Again, I apologize for adding the whole thing, but a lot of it is necessary to understand the issue and I don't have much time left in my workday to strip the unnecessary parts out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a flag to prevent the event firing when the animation is happening:

```
var isSwiping = false;

function startSwipe() {
  if (isSwiping) {
    return false;
  } else {
    isSwiping = true;
    $("button#back, button#next").attr("disabled", true);
    return true;
  }
}

function endSwipe() {
  $("button#back, button#next").removeAttr("disabled");
  isSwiping = false;
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  if (startSwipe()) {
    ...
      // Inside animate callback:
      endSwipe();
    ...
}

...

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);        
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, false);

...

function handleTouchStart(evt) {
  if (startSwipe()) {
    ...                                      
  }
};                                                

function handleTouchMove(evt) {
  if (isSwiping) {
    ...
  }
};

function handleTouchEnd(evt) {
  endSwipe();
};
```

Comment: I have edited my code exactly as laid out here, and I can see the flags working, however, if I swipe multiple times in succession, I am still getting overlapped divs.  It seems as though one animate might fail every so many swipes, and that div stops moving until I back swipe to it and forward again.  The issue is definitely in the animation.  Any ideas?

Comment: updated, sorry for the delay.  The nextPrev() doesn't work when swiping if you check for startSwipe() at the beginning, though the buttons work perfectly.  I removed that and tested without, which works but was still getting glitches when swiping left and right alternating fast.

Comment: Figured it out.  I was calling endSwipe() on both the nextPrev() and on touchend listener, which ended it prematurely.  I removed touchend listener and it works perfect.  Thank you, ariel!